# Playwright - What is the meaning of page.locator('article')

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

By reading the Playwright documentation https://playwright.dev/docs/pom, I find these lines of code:

`page.locator('article div.markdown ul > li > a');`

`expect(page.locator('article')).toContainText('Page Object Model is a common pattern');`

When I examine the source of the web pages, I can't find anything related to `'article'`. There is no custom tag named `article`, or CSS class named `article`

Can anybody explain to me the meaning of `page.locator('article')` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a CSS selector for a standard HTML element, [`<article>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article).

Any CSS selector that has no special syntax like a `.` or `#` prefix is simply an HTML tag. `page.locator("p")` selects `<p>` elements by tag name, and `page.locator("article")` selects `<article>` elements by tag name.